# How to print A5 as A6 on A4 in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

As title says, I have a Word document with flash cards, question-answer alternating odd-even pages, all those are A5. I'd like to print them on A4 paper but 4 pairs per sheet, to save paper, also, those are short questions, so A6 is enough. How do I set the printing job, to not only fit the pages but also keep correct pairs of Q-A on one resulting A6 sheet? Seems to be very tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LOL, that was a tricky one. First of all, I exported DOCX to PDF, much easier to handle it in Acrobat Reader (hence the name, I guess). Now, what I did is:
1) Print 'odd pages only'
2) Multiple pages, 4 per sheet, 'horizontal' order
3) One side only, portrait, do not auto-rotate pages
4) Print!
5) Turn the resulting stack of papers, setting almost same settings but 'even pages only' with 'horizontal reversed' order. Nice.